# attempt at using htaccess rewrite rules - not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a simple website using PHP and have gotten stuck at trying to format the URLs into having "pretty" URLs.

Currently, this site is not running of the root directory; ie not from "localhost" but instead from a sub directory, ie localhost/resources/vuws/. So to link to the correct files I've defined the "Site URL" to "http://localhost/resources/vuws/".

As such:

```
define("SITEURL", "http://localhost/resources/vuws/");
```

This is how I'm directing users to different pages:

```
    $title = 'vUWS';
    $heading = 'Welcome';
    $content = 'index.php';

$page = @$_GET['p'];
        switch($page) {
          case 'how-to-upload-a-file':
            $title = 'How to upload a file';
            $content = 'how-to-upload-a-file.php';
            break;
          case 'how-to-make-an-announcement':
            $title = 'How to make an announcement';
            $content = 'how-to-make-an-announcement.php';
            break;
          case 'how-to-add-teaching-staff':
            $title = 'How to add teaching staff';
            $content = "how-to-add-teaching-staff.php";
            break;
        }
```

Then in the content area:

```
<?php
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/pages/$content");
?>
```

And this is my attempt at using redirects in htaccess but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /resources/vuws/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I try to access "localhost/resources/vuws/how-to-upload-a-file", it directs to just index.php. I believe it may not be receiving a value for $_GET['p'], therefore it's not entering the switch statement and so it's then using the default value for $content which is "index.php".

If I access it via "localhost/resources/vuws/?p=how-to-upload-a-file" it works. But if I try "localhost/resources/vuws/how-to-upload-a-file" it doesn't work.

Currently, I'm not too sure how to approach this issue or a better way to debug this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Johnny

PS: At the moment using Virtual Hosts is not an option, it needs to be able to run from a sub directory.

Comment: RewriteLog good, RewriteBase bad (unless there is a specific reason / as of now the subdir looks distinct from the incoming request path). Also the `require_once` wouldn't trigger a HTTP redirect by itself (unless your switch/dispatcher code does something else).

Comment: check this link, you will get idea to solve your problem: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thanks for the replies; I've looked at the link and it states that the flag `[QSA]` causes query strings to be combined, which is what I want so I have included it in, but it still isn't directing properly, it just goes to index.php. This is what I have in the RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /resources/vuws/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]`